# java.util.vector$1

Tags: java, enumeration, inner-classes

```
enumeration e=vector.elements
```

But vector class does not implement Enumeration, then how comes it is returning Enumeration Reference. But `e` is refering to java.util.vector$1 . What is "Vector$1"???

Answer (score 6):

`Vector$1` is an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm). `Vector.elements()` creates a new instance of this anonymous class, which implements the `Enumeration` interface.

Here's the source code for `Vector.elements()` (badly formatted, as usual):

```
public Enumeration<E> elements() {
return new Enumeration<E>() {
    int count = 0;

    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
    return count < elementCount;
    }

    public E nextElement() {
    synchronized (Vector.this) {
        if (count < elementCount) {
        return (E)elementData[count++];
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Vector Enumeration");
    }
};
}
```